# dataflow bigquery unit tests

Tags: google-bigquery, integration-testing, google-cloud-dataflow, endly

I have a dataflow pipeline that reads data from files in GCS, transforms it and places the results to BQ.
I created the tests that checks the expected TableRows are in the PCollection, but
how I can verify the data that will be written into BQ is right according to the db schema I provided?

```
        tableRowPCollection.apply(BigQueryIO.Write.named("Write to table").to(options.getTableName())
            .withCreateDisposition(CREATE_IF_NEEDED).withSchema(someSchema).
                    withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE));
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to verify that `BigQueryIO` itself does not corrupt the data in your `PCollection`?

I don't think there is a good way to do that - except for, of course, actually running the pipeline and then reading the data back and verifying it (you can use `BigQueryIO.Read` to read the data back and some `PAssert`'s to verify it) - but I was assuming you're looking for something more lightweight.

However, you can also take a look at how `BigQueryIO` itself is tested, e.g. [this test](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/test/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIOReadTest.java#L273). The important method is `withTestServices` (both `BigQueryIO.Read` and `BigQueryIO.Write` have it) - however, it is a package-local implementation detail and not intended to be used by pipeline writers.